# Install multiple MPI libraries and switch between them on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, mpi

For educational purposes I'd like to set up several MPI libraries, e.g. OpenMPI, MPICH, and Intel MPI along with different backend compilers (gcc, clang, icc) on the same machine running Ubuntu 18.04.4 TLS. What is the best way to do this so as to be able to switch between them easily when I need to see how a particular code works with one MPI library/compiler or another?

So far I only managed to select a compiler via mpicc's `-cc` command line argument (MPICH) or `OMPI_CC` environment variable (OpenMPI). But when I install OpenMPI after MPICH, for example, mpicc from MPICH seems to be getting replaced with the one from OpenMPI and I am basically losing access to MPICH:

```
$ sudo apt install mpich
$ mpicc -show
gcc -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -I/usr/include/mpich -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpich

$ sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev
$ mpicc -show
gcc -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -pthread -L/usr//lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib -lmpi
```

Is it possible to have both and choose which one I currently want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use docker containers for this. It will provide you with:

- Multiple containers with all types of combinations of compilers and libraries while making sure that only 1 compiler and 1 library is present in each container.
- A really 'clean' environment to code in (If you are learning/teaching you don't want to use systems with too much extra 'junk'. They will only make things more complicated)
- A environment that looks practically exactly the same on each type of computer (If you are teaching you want all your students to see exactly the same thing)

Create a `Dockerfile` with `ubuntu:18.04` as base-image and buildargs like `COMPILER` and `MPILIB`. That way you can quickly create multiple containers that all have different combinations of compilers and mpi libraries.